# Is there a way to cancel from inside ordered clause?

Tags: c, openmp, cancellation

I'm developing a program that calculates a certain number of prime numbers using multiple threads. Now I have run into a problem of exiting from threads after said number of primes.

I've tried `#pragma omp cancel for`, but I cannot use it inside an ordered clause. Is there another way to "break" the loop?

```c
void get_primes(prime_type start, prime_type end) {
  #pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic) shared(prime_counter)
  for (candidate = start; candidate <= end; candidate += 2) {
    if (is_prime(candidate)) {
      #pragma omp ordered
      {
        primes[prime_counter] = candidate;
        prime_counter++;
        if (prime_counter >= max_primes) {
          #pragma omp cancel for
        }
        #pragma omp cancellation point for
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to immediately "break" the loop when I've found the desired number of primes and if I'm not mistaken that must be done inside the ordered clause.

Comment: You can have two conditions in the `for` loop. `candidate <= end && prime_counter < max_primes;`

Comment: @WeatherVane No, that is not a valid loop form for `omp for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to cancel an ordered loop.

> A loop construct that is canceled must not have an ordered clause.

(cf. 2.14.1 of the OpenMP standard)

One of the workaround to emulate cancellation is to add a skip at the beginning of the loop, e.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic) shared(prime_counter)
for (candidate = start; candidate <= end; candidate += 2) {
  if (prime_counter >= max_primes) {
    continue;
  }
  if (is_prime(candidate)) {
```

However, that is not yet a thread safe access to `prime_counter`. In order to avoid race conditions, you must do something along the lines of:

```
  int local_prime_counter;
  #pragma omp atomic read
  local_prime_counter = prime_counter;
  if (local_prime_counter >= max_primes)

  ...

  #pragma omp atomic update
  prime_counter++;
```

P.S. I'm not quite 100% sure if it is standard conforming to have a conditional `ordered` construct.

Comment: Could you please explain what thread safety means? Will the result be any different using a thread safe approach?

Comment: If you do not add the `atomic` clauses when accessing `prime_counter`, the result is undefined. Most likely it will just work. Maybe you will perform significant additional work cause the local copy is not updated. Unlikely, but possible, the loop will never stop or stop prematurely.